# What are Array Indexes?

Tags: c#, arrays, indexing

I know that `List<T>` indexers, for example, resemble properties. Taken from msdn:

> Indexers allow instances of a class or struct to be indexed **just like**
>   **arrays**. Indexers resemble properties except that their accessors take
>   parameters.

But I can't understand why the following happens:

```
int[] myArray = new int[0];
List<int> myList = new List<int>();

Interlocked.Increment(ref myArray[0]);  // fine

Interlocked.Increment(ref myList[0]);   //CS0206    A property or indexer may not be passed as an out or ref parameter
```

Aren't they supposed to work in the same way?

Comment: Pls check Mike Chamberlain answer on the duplicate question. Despite it is not marked as the correct answer is the more detailed one and it does explains crystal clear why this is not possible. Hope it helps.

Comment: @Christos Imo it doesn't answer the question

Comment: @Christos I'm not asking about the error.

Comment: @Christos I agree with Zbigniew.  The real question is why it works for an array, not why it doesn't for a list indexer.

Comment: @ArthurCastro alright, I opened again the question. I hope you will the answer you are looking for.

Comment: It's because arrays are special.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The indexer for `List<T>` allows you to access the elements using properties (Methods) which makes it look like an array. You can't pass the generated method by `ref` as if you wrote :

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref myList.GetItem.get_Item(0));
```

But accessing array's elements is not though an indexer. Accessing array elements is **directly supported in the CLR**. So `array[i]` returns a variable that can be passed by `ref`.

**From C# Specs:**

> Even though the syntax for accessing an indexer element is the same as
>   that for an array element, an indexer element is not classified as a
>   variable. Thus, it is not possible to pass an indexer element as a ref
>   or out argument.

This is the indexer of `List<T>` (which internally uses an array):

```
public T this[int index]
{
    get
    { // some checks removed 
        return _items[index];
    }

    set { _items[index] = value;}
}
```

### From IL Side:

Accessing an array element generates this direct IL instruction:

`IL_0014:  ldelem.i4`

Accessing a List's element through indexer generates this:

```
IL_001b:  callvirt   instance !0 class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::get_Item(int32)
```

So, it is the same c# syntax. But the generated IL is completely different.

Comment: "Even though the syntax for accessing an indexer element is the same as that for an array element, an indexer element is not classified as a variable.". Exactly what I wanted to read: The index from arrays return the variable itself.

Answer (score 4):

It's because indexers are properties and properties are ultimately functions. Because they are functions, they don't (*necessarily*) refer to a specific location in memory like an array index does. If the language DID allow it, developers would be able to easily break the reference and out semantics and it just wouldn't work right. Case in point:

```
public class Foo {
        public int this[int x] {
            get {
                return 1;
            }
            set {
                //meh. whatever. 
            }
        }
    }
```

If I pass `Foo[0]` as an out parameter, what just happened? In this case, I don't even set *anything*. This completely breaks the semantics of `ref` and `out`.

Comment: Beat me to it, though I would have just referenced line 174 here...http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs

Comment: 'indexers are properties and properties are ultimately functions'. Using this same logic, array indexes are properties and ultimately functions too, but they act differently, as you can see in the example in the question.

Comment: No, indexes and indexers are two different things.